# Translation of "I am in college because of work"

Tags: translation, business-japanese, english-to-japanese

> I am in college because of work.

What I mean by that is that I want to say that I am in college due to some work, like as a guest for a lecture. I attended college for some work I had with the teachers.

I was communicating with a Japanese online and I made the following sentence which was corrected by her:

> 大学に入っていたから私が働くのを待っています

I thought it sounded strange, so here is my own attempt:

> しごとがあるので大学にいます

Are these sentences correct? What's the best way to say it in Japanese?

Comment: Your friend's translation doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I know, what would be the proper translation? I think she must've not got what I had to say. I want to say 'I am in college because of work'. What do you think?

Comment: The English phrasing is unclear to begin with. Do you mean that you attend college (mostly/solely) because it will be good for your career?

Comment: What exactly does `I am in college because of work` mean? That as part of your work you're visiting the college (ie as a guest for a lecture)? Or that you're taking some classes to acquire some missing skills you need at work? Or sth. else?

Comment: @blutorange Yes, I want to say that I am in college due to some work, like as a guest for a lecture. Sorry to cause so much confusion but I literally couldn't think of anything else when I replied. What do you think? What would be the answer?

Comment: @nkjt no, I meant I attended college for some work I had with the teachers.

Comment: @blutorange What do think of this?しごとがあるので大学にいます

Comment: @moefetish "I am in college" is an idiom for saying you are enrolled in that school. In terms of the English, do you mean "I was at a university today due to a job" ?

Comment: @virmaior Yes, due to some work, I was at the college or university.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

仕事があるので大学にいます is grammatical but misleading. Without any further context, it sounds as if you were regularly employed by that college, and you had to be at the office of the college because you haven't finished the task for the day.

If you are a visitor, and want to say "I was at a university today due to a job," some better ways to say it are:

- とある仕事の関係で、○○大学にいます。
- とある仕事で、大学に来ています。

とある (≒certain, some) is not mandatory, but by using it you can clearly tell it's not your regular job.

大学に入っていたから私が働くのを待っています does not make sense at all to me.

Comment: Ah, I get it. This is really helpful, thank you for your answer. I think the second one sounds good to me. Also, the one which I posted which you said is incorrect was sent by some other Japanese friend if mine. I am surprised at just how many variations a sentence can have. Yet again, thank you. I am very poor at pairing up sentences into one single sentence and have to improve.